# I get an error in FF (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI)

Tags: firefox

Just wondering if there is an easy fix for this problem.

The full error is: 
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIURL.spec]"  nsresult: "0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://fastdial/content/file.js :: anonymous :: line 218"  data: no]

And line 218 is

nsiUrl.spec = url;

I give you all of the code from the file if you need it...

Thanks
Ingalls

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your variable `url` is, it is not a valid URI.